# white page when content-length > 8000

Tags: php, apache, xampp

On a private project I stumbled over a weird problem: On page load when the header-information `Content-Length` reaches 8000 and I add a single character (or more) to the output(e.g. `<a>12</a>` instead of `<a>1</a>`), the page will be white and the body (!) of the HTTP-Packet will be empty (also: `Content-Length: 0`). Debug information (e.g. with PhpConsole for Chrome) is transported correctly, though and when I parse my code via command `php index.php` no error is thrown and the content of the page is returned correctly.

Since this problem happens at exactly 8000 I guess it is related to a setting made by a human and not some buffer overflow or something similar. Does anyone know that problem and know how to fix it?

**Update:**
My problem seems to be related to [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30649), which according to the comment is not a bug but a feature called "chunked encoding".

I could quickfix my problem by adding `header('Content-Length: '. ob_get_length() );` to the end of my script, but I'd like to understand the problem. So if anyone could explain to me where this problem comes from and how I could fix it permanently and in an appropriate way, that would be great. :)

Comment: check server access\error logs

Comment: Searching for "apache content length 8000" yields a few promising results. Can't verify any of them due to lack of example and specific details, though. You're not alone.

Comment: @Marvin: Sadly, most of the results seem to be about something with "port 8000", so they don't help me at all.
@Dagon: access log for a refresh: `[11/Apr/2016:01:55:42 +0200] "GET /Project/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8003` and it stops there instead of loading the .js-files.
error log: nothing.

Answer (score 1):

i think when web servers want to send data to clients they will do that in one of two ways below:

1. data less than 8000 octets (bytes in all new computers) will be attached with a `Content-Length` header
2. for data larger than 8000 octets they will omit `Content-Length` but they will add `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

now, when data is larger than 8000 octets and `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, At the time of sending the headers, the web server is unaware of how much data it will finally send, (you can aware him using `ob_get_length()`)

i think your code may have a feature to show the downlaod-progress to the user, which is based on data lower than 8000 and `Content-Length` header, so when you want to get responses more than 8000, that code may break and breaking your page as an according consequence

---

and you may ask why 8000 octets?
well that is a number which is in http specs (rfc 9110 up to 9112), it is not specific for using as an criteria for chunking data, but web servers may use it:

for example read [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9112#name-request-line):

> Various ad hoc limitations on request-line length are found in
> practice. It is RECOMMENDED that all HTTP senders and recipients
> support, at a minimum, request-line lengths of **8000** octets

Comment: you deserve a medal for answering this more than 7 years later.